# Sort varchar datatype with numeric characters

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a `varchar` column that needs to be sorted by the number included in it. The data is similar to:

```
Group 1
Group 10
Group 11
Group 12
Group 13
Group 14
Group 15
Group 16
Group 17
Group 18
Group 19
Group 2
Group 20
Group 3
Group 4
Group 5
Group 6
Group 7
Group 8
Group 9
Test Group
```

I want the output like this where the value is sorted by the number.

```
Group 1
Group 2
Group 3
Group 4
Group 5…..
```

Comment: "How I want to use order by if my data"  ...huh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TRY like below, It will help you..

```
SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, Replace(ColumnName, 'Group',''))
```

**SQL Fiddle :** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e14a6/7

*Another Way*

```
SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName 
ORDER BY LEN(ColumnName),ColumnName
```

**SQL Fiddle :** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e14a6/6

*Another Way*

```
SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName order by 
case when 
    PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',ColumnName) = 0 
THEN 
    data
ELSE
    cast(Left(ColumnName,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',ColumnName)-1) as int) 
END
```

**SQL Fiddle :** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14eb5/2

*Another Way*

Here i have add another solution by using [**Common Table Expression**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) Try this...

```
with tempCTE(Data, pos)
as
(select data, Patindex('%[0-9]%', data)  from sample),
tempCTE2(name, num)
as
(select SUBSTRING(data, 0, pos) name , cast(SUBSTRING(data, pos , LEN(data)) as int) num from tempCTE)
select name + CAST(num as varchar(10)) num1 from tempCTE2 order by name, num asc
```

**SQL Fiddle :** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14eb5/3

Comment: But group is not fixed i may also have some other string jai1,balaji10,jai2,ganesh3

Comment: i tried the Another way as u said, but it sort according to length ie i am having jai3, balaji10 jai3 is coming first, but i want the output to be balaji10, jai3

Comment: that query is printing like this way balaji1
balaji10
balaji2
balaji11
balaji3
jai3
ganesh10 but i need balaji1,balaji2,balaj3,balaji10,balaji11,jai3,ganesh10

Comment: SELECT name FROM sample1
ORDER BY LEFT(name,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',name)-1), -- alphabetical sort
CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(name,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',name),LEN(name)))

Comment: @jai: Try the new solution that i have added, i have used **Common Table Expression**